# Cannot connect through SSH after updating to 22.04

Tags: ssh

After updating ubuntu to 22.04, I'm cannot connet through SSH. I tried with a private server and then tried to push to gitlab, and in both cases, I get a similar message `ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable`

I'm running kernel `5.15.0-30-generic`, and I've tried all the proposed solutions [listed here](https://linuxhint.com/fix_connection_refused_ubuntu/) with no success. Any further help will be welcome!

Comment: you don't have a "connection refused" error, you have "network unreachable". Do you have an Internet connection at all? can you ping gitlab.com?

Comment: It seems so as I'm writing here from that PC. `ping gitlab.com` works fine